# Rename files but retain files original time stamp in name

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, rename, date

I have a list of a few hundred files. They are currently as below:

```
filename.New_20160901.dat
filename.New_20160902.dat
...
```

etc., all the way up to

```
filename.New_<current date>.dat
```

I have a process that currently looks to pick files up from a landing directory, but in a totally different file name format.

What i want to do is rename the files but retain the date. For example, if i was to change one file it would be like:

```
$ mv filename.New_20160902.dat FILE_NAME_NEW.20160902.dat
```

Easily done for one file, but how can i do this for a list of files. I want to extract the date part of the old filename, store it as a variable and `mv` that old file to a new file with the new filename, keeping the date part the same.

Thanks

Comment: [Hey see this approach, hope you could find your solution in this way.](https://serverfault.com/a/70947)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
rename -n s/filename.New_/FILE_NAME_NEW./ filename.New*
```

If you are OK with proposed renaming, run without `-n`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
for x in *; do
    mv "${x}" FILE_NAME_NEW."${x#filename.New_}"
done
```

Use `echo` in front of `mv` first, so you can see what the effect is before renaming the files. "${x}" is the variable with your filename (e.g. `filename.New_20160901.dat`) and "${x#filename.New_}" is the filename with `filename.New_` removed if it is at the beginning (e.g. `20160901.dat`).

Answer (score 0):

To match a file that contains the time stamp (and not other files) use:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for x in filename.New_[0-9]*.dat; do
    echo "file --> $x"

    echo    mv "${x}" "${x/filename.New_/FILE_NAME_NEW.}"
done
```

Remove the echo in front of mv to actually perform the move (after you are happy with the files selected with the script).